# Extract attachments from .eml file

Tags: linux, open-source, email, document-converter, media-converter

Forwarded emails are unfortunately sometimes transmitted by Outlook as `.eml` files, which are unusable for normal users. In particular, extracting attachments from `.eml` files is a challenge.

What software can extract all attachments contained in a `.eml` file?

Requirements:

- Free
- Open source
- Runs on Linux
- Output a file per attachment, with the intended name.
- No need to compile (binaries available, or script)
- Reasonably fast to install, I would rather avoid having to set up a particular email client program just to process this `.eml` file.

Comment: I don't know the exact features of [LookOut (Addon)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/lookout/) for Thunderbird, but it gives in provides very good interoperability with the proprietary formats. You may try if this fixes it.

Answer (score 22):

From the definition of **[munpack](http://ftp.andrew.cmu.edu/pub/mpack/)**:

> Unpack messages in MIME or split-uuencode format.
>   Munpack are utilities for encoding and decoding (respectively) binary files in MIME (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions) format mail messages.

To Install:

```
sudo apt-get install mpack
```

To extract the eml contents

```
munpack 1.eml
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get hold of MIME parts that don't have filenames, e.g. the text and HTML, then try

```
sudo apt install maildir-utils
mu extract source.eml --save-all
```

Docs: https://manpages.debian.org/testing/maildir-utils/mu-extract.1.en.html

Comment: maildir-utils rocks

Answer (score 0):

Those are all good answers, but for completeness's sake, I figured I would add more such options because some of the aforementioned tools might not be as readily available as others.

> The [perl-MIME-tools](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Tools) package includes a variety of command-line tools
> for processing MIME-encoded messages, including [`mimeexplode`](https://metacpan.org/release/DSKOLL/MIME-tools-5.510/source/examples/mimeexplode):
>
> ````
> Takes one or more files from the command line that contain MIME
> messages, and explodes their contents out into subdirectories of the
> current working directory.  The subdirectories are just called "msg0",
> "msg1", "msg2", etc.  Existing directories are skipped over. ```
> ````
>
> The [`ripmime`](https://pldaniels.com/ripmime/) command is packaged in [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL), if that meets your "packaged
> by the vendor" requirements.

This is partly taken from [this Server Fault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/389346), links added by myself.